# Transform String to LocalDate --> Unsupported field: NanoOfDay :

Tags: java, java-8, localdate

I want to transform a String to a LocalDate in a specific format (`yyyy-MM-dd`), My string is already in format of **ISO_LOCAL_DATE**.

**Code**

```
 private LocalDate myDate;
 public MyObject(String name, LocalDate myDate) {...}

 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
 MyObject myObject = new myObject("my object name", LocalDate.parse("2019-03-01", formatter));
```

**Error**

> java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: NanoOfDay

**Already tried**

```
object = new Object("object name", (LocalDate) formatter.parse("2019-03-01"));

use SimpleDateFormatter
```

Comment: Are you sure that you post the tested code ? The formatter seems ok.

Comment: The error most likely happens somewhere else, in code that you did not show us, because the code you posted to parse a string such as `2019-03-01` to a `LocalDate` is correct and does not throw an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`.

Comment: I bet you are using *joda.time* package instead of *java.time*

Comment: @AsierAranbarri then the tags are wrong. The [localdate] even says in the tag-wiki that its from `java.time`

Comment: @Lino just compiled the code with java.time and no errors whatsoever. But it does accept another include, *joda*'s DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: I'm just a stupid man sorry ... I will delete this post. Indeed, the code works fine, I was looking to the wrong place ... Sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> If the String is formatted like *ISO_LOCAL_DATE*, you can parse the
>   String directly, no need conversion.

**In Java-8**

```
 public static void main(String[] argv) {
            String date = "2019-03-01";
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
            System.out.println(localDate);
        }
```

**Output**:

```
2019-03-01
```

Comment: It runs at my end, i am in Java 8.

Comment: dont know how i deserve **downvote**, can the user add explanation where i am wrong.

Comment: It is a bit my fault because I asked a stupid question, so I will accept your answer to comfort you :p

Comment: @N.Lamblin, its ok though, i just wonder why someone gets so pissed, btw i have edited my answer with java 8 title.